# Xcode 6.4 Scheme Option Disappeared in El Capitan Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

After I upgraded my Mac from Yosemite to El Capitan developer beta, the scheme option button in Xcode 6.4 is disappeared from the tool bar:

[image]

But Xcode 7 beta works fine

[image]

Is this an El Capitan bug? Is there any solution to fix this apart from rolling back to Yosemite? Thank

Comment: Have you solved this issue..since I updated to El Capitan I am also facing this issue

Comment: @RahulMishra Before Xcode  7 GM was released I used matt's answer as a temporary walk around solution. But now I am using Xcode 7.0.1 and the button shows correctly.

Comment: I also switch to Xcode 7 but I am afraid will it affect my older projects or not that's why I want to use Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need that button; the same options are available from the Product menu. So even though it's a bug, you can work around it for now, easily enough.

Answer (score 10):

It is a UI bug and will probably be fixed soon. I've been working around the issue by dragging the Xcode window so that it is very wide (wider than my monitor). After a certain width, the scheme selector comes back into view.

Comment: Or just drag the window of Xcode 6 to an external display which is wide enough to show the scheme option~

Comment: I confirm the above is correct.  If the Window is stretched beyond normal the scheme selector appears. Seem like an autolayout issue on El Capitan.

Answer (score 6):

Make xCode fullscreen. It works properly only in fullscreen mode.[image]

*UPDATED* Method valid only for MBP 15 inch (retina)

Comment: @naz try to do that in new desktop space

Comment: @naz looks like my method valid only for MBP 15 inch (retina)

Comment: Worked for me also on a MBP 15 inch retina, kinda weird, seems like a size issue with the screen size maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you are not using any variant of `xcode 6`. I also got the same issue with `xcode 6.4`, but when I used `xcode 7`, everything was working fine.

So get `xcode 7`. It will work

Here is a snippet of bug with `OS X El Capitan Developer Beta 7 Release Notes`

[image]

Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/rn-osx-10.11/) link for more.

Answer (score 0):

that was a UI bug and just expand your Xcode window, than you can see that option will appears in Xcode.