# Xcode 6 not showing scheme menu dropdown

Tags: xcode6

On some occasions (like now), Xcode 6 does not show the scheme menu selection drop-down list. It normally sits close to the "play" button. I cannot for my life find anyway to access that scheme selection even from the menu. How do I turn it on?

[image: Scheme-drop-down-less Xcode 6]

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDialog.html), the "Scheme Menu" should sit in the toolbar. It is just to access the "Scheme Editor". For me the Scheme Menu is not showing.

**Update/fix: Ok it's not a fix but I realize we can reach the scheme editor from menu: Product->Scheme**

Oh. I just updated to OS X El Capitan GM seed. It might have something to do with this. But I am pretty sure I saw this issue a few times back on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Weird. Did you try hiding the toolbar and showing it again? ("View" -> "Hide Toolbar"). Does it fix itself on relaunch?

Comment: Yes. I just hooked up a shortcut key to the Toolbar toggle. And am toggling it on off. It just looks weird, like it tries to show something but fails then "swallows" whatever that was and falls back to that thin toolbar line.

Comment: I found a scheme menu in Product menu.

Comment: (by the way, Xcode 7 is in GM now, and you can submit apps built with it. Unless you aren't ready to make the switch to Swift 2, or are otherwise stuck with another Xcode 6-only feature, I would consider moving to the newer version...)

Comment: Great; does it help? I see there's a "Restore" menu item. Wonder what it does...

Comment: Of course, I will likely go Xcode 7 shortly, I still rely on the previous/current iOS SDK. SDK 9 is so picky about foreign URLs and frameworks that need to be recompiled. I use lots of 3rd party frameworks for ad networks. They always update very slow. :-P

Comment: Now that you mention it, I remember reading somewhere in the developer portal that you should use Xcode 7 with El Capitan, because it doesn't play well with Xcode 6... Perhaps your best option is to stick with Yosemite for a  while... Also, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220697/xcode-6-4-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan-beta-2-beta-3

Comment: Also, I guess I could use Xcode 7 in El Capitan if there were an easy way to select iOS SDK 8.4 instead of just the latest one which would be iOS SDK 9. But there seems to be no easy way.

Comment: Fwiw, I still see this bug in the currently released Xcode 7. It happens not very frequently, but sometimes... And sometimes I'm able to fix it by restarting Xcode.

Comment: FWIW I see the issue with Xcode 6.4 / El Capitan.  Exact same symptom: Scheme drop-down appears momentarily and is "swallowed".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6.4 Scheme Option Disappeared in El Capitan Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276768/xcode-6-4-scheme-option-disappeared-in-el-capitan-beta)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and kicked myself when i realised that the scheme dropdown gets HIDDEN if the window is too narrow.

Edit: found a duplicate to this - [Destination toolbar disappeared on XCode 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318316/destination-toolbar-disappeared-on-xcode-6-4)

Maximise you window!

Comment: I almost always use full screen. It doesn't help. Mostly using a MacBook Pro, is that too small for Xcode?

Comment: I use 1920x1200, tried 1440x900 and that is indeed too narrow in my case, see before: http://ibin.co/2JEkxj7eQCUi and after widening slightly: http://ibin.co/2JElBmD81esZ It is pretty ridiculous, I think there is a bug before the scheme is showing the simulator ID - so it is wider than it should be!